# android dev on 64-bit mac

Tags: android, macos, 32bit-64bit

I'm considering switching to from PC to Mac but I do Android development. I've read that Android development is only for 32-bit Macs. Is there a way around that problem so that I can continue to do Android development if I buy a 64-bit Mac?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android development will be in fact in 32 bits but Mac OS X is intelligent enough to run 64 bits and 32 bits binary on a 64 bits processor. You will not have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could always run a 32 bit instance of windows xp in virtual machine on your mac.  Not ideal, but it works pretty well.  Parallels would be better though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had no problems doing android dev on a mac.  The SDK installs without a problem and you can just install whichever version of Eclipse suits you.