# Hard time installing ia32-lib on mac osx

Tags: linux, macos

I'm trying to install the ia32-lib on my mac leopard osx 10.5.8 in order to be able to create some Android components like the SD card, the issue is that i get the following error:

```
E: Couldn't find package ia32-libs
```

so i thought it was an update issue and thus updated with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But still i get the same error,

another thing that i have noticed is that by running a cache scan like:

```
sudo apt-cache search ia32-libs
```

Nothing is returned, so the update actually did not fetch this library,

Have you ever experienced this? have some hints?
Unfortunately by looking around the web i have only found hints for Debian and Ubuntu.
Thank you,

Comment: I don't think you need ia32-libs for Mac OSX.  Q: Doesn't the Android SDK + Eclipse work OK as-is on your Mac?  Q: If not, please specify exactly what problems you're encountering?

Comment: Hi, ok indeed you are right, as standard, "apt-get" is not available on osx, i had to install Fink.Eclipse and the SDK are working fine except for when i try to create the SD card for the virtual device from the Manager, at that point i get : Failed to create the sd card which according to most of the topic with the same issue that i see around, is related to the fact that android runs on  32bit since java6 for Leopard is 64 bit, i think i need need that 32bit library, in the tools dir i have already set the permissions to read write and execute so this is not the problem...

Comment: Your question is not "how do I install ia32-libs?" then, it's "how do I install a 32-bit JRE on OS X?".

Comment: Hi Ignacio, as far as i know the 32 bit is there by default when using java 5, then with java 6 there is the 64 bit, java 6 indeed on leopard is available only on 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK:

1) You've got two threads open on the same question:

- [Hard time installing ia32-lib on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223192/hard-time-installing-ia32-lib-on-mac-osx)
- [Android: Failed to create SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221401/android-failed-to-create-sd-card)

2) More to the point, I honestly think you're barking up the wrong tree.

I *don't* think you somehow need to get ia32-libs installed on Mac OSX.  Heck, I don't even know if there *is* an ia32-libs for Mac OSX.  Yes, It's necessary on some 64-bit Linux platforms.  AFAIK, it is *not* necessary on 64-bit Mac OSX.  Honest!

3) Please look at these links:

- http://www.buzztouch.com/files/howtos/Setting_Up_Your_Android_Development_Environment_For_MacOSX_v1.0.pdf
- [android dev on 64-bit mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581874/android-dev-on-64-bit-mac)
- http://relentlessinquiry.com/2011/03/02/how-i-built-my-mac-os-x-android-development-environment/
- http://marakana.com/support/android_setup.html

Comment: Hi - I see from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168172/android-adt-not-starting-on-eclipse/) that you got it working.  You *were* able to use the 64-bit JVM; the trick was you needed to use JDK 1.6 (instead of Java 1.5).  Cool :)!

Comment: I have java version "1.6.0_65", still i'm getting the error. how to solve this ?